# Is there a way to specify AWS_SESSION_TOKEN when using SQLWorkbench and Athena JDBC driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc

I am using SQLWorkbench to connect to AWS Athena and SQLWorkbench Variables section to specify AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.  This works. However, when I have to connect to accounts, which require AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, the connection fails.  I can connect by modifying credentials file, but that's inconvenient. Is there a better way?

Comment: I am using AthenaJDBC42.jar

Comment: I'm also trying to execute query from SQLWorkbench/J which needs to connect to AWS athena. But even after setting the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, it prompts for the password? could you specify how you setup AWS key and secret keys in SQLWorkbench/J that works for you. It would be helpful for others as well. using the driver url as "jdbc:https://com.amazonaws.us-east-1.athena" and driver "com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver".

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from AWS support, and at this point, according to them, it appears that the driver does not support AWS_SESSION_TOKEN parameter.

Answering the question, which appeared on the thread, if you have to use session token, it appears that the only way is to modify your aws credentials file.  This can be done either  by adding a section or modifying default.  Here is an example of a connection string for the former, where simba_session is a profile in credentials:
`jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-west-2;AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;AwsCredentialsProviderArguments=simba_session;`

If you don't need to use session token, you can specify AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY by pressing the Variables button and adding the keys/values.  In this case, the connection string can look like this:
`jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-west-2;AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;`

Also note that you can add S3OutputLocation (if needed) and a Workgroup (if needed) by pressing Extended Properties button and adding keys/values, rather than doing it in the connection string.